# work with 3 decimals in python

Tags: python, numpy, decimal

Is there a way to tell python that I want to perform (all) my aritmetics rounding the results (always) to 3 decimals?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jackiekazil/6201722 this looks useful

Answer (score 2):

```
num=1.2356
print round(num,3)
## Use round function and pass number of decimal places upto which you want to round
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's only a matter of display, you can use [`numpy.set_printoptions(precision=3)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Comment: Thanks! can I ask you if Matlab and Python perform the aritmetics using the same num type? I am comparing results obtained with Matlab and Python and they don't match